# Fixing ValueError in python for calculating portfolio standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, finance

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation of a portfolio of stocks. However, I am receiving the following error on the last line of code
`ValueError: shapes (21,21) and (25,) not aligned: 21 (dim 1) != 25 (dim 0)`

Any advice on how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated :)

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#get adjusted closing prices of selected companies with Quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'ENTER KEY HERE'
stocks = ['KHC', 'HPE', 'AAPL', 'GOOG', 'MSFT', 'GE', 'WMT', 'KO',
      'XOM', 'IBM', 'MO', 'JNJ', 'CVX', 'MRK', 'WFC', 'HD', 'ORCL',
      'MMM', 'FB', 'F', 'T', 'BA', 'CSCO','HPQ', 'GILD']

#length of stocks
noa = len(stocks)

#obtain data from quandl
data = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker = stocks,
                    qopts = { 'columns': ['date', 'ticker','adj_close']},
                    date = { 'gte': '1995-1-1', 'lte': '2010-12-31' }, paginate=True)
data.head()

#sort the adjusted closing prices by tickers
#reorganise data pulled by setting date as index with
#columns of tickers and their corresponding adjusted prices
table = data.pivot(index = 'date', columns='ticker')
table.head()

#calculate daily and annual returns of the stocks
returns_daily = np.log(table / table.shift(1))

#factor of 252 trading days to annualise
returns_annual = returns_daily.mean() * 252

#covariance of returns of the stock
cov = returns_daily.cov() * 252

#generates random numbers between 0 and 1 and then 
#normalises the values such that the sum of all values equals 1
weights = np.random.random(noa)
weights /= np.sum(weights)

#expected portfolio return
returns = np.sum(returns_daily.mean()[:, None] * weights) 

#expected portfolio standard deviation
np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov() * 252, weights))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you get not all stocks from quandl (21 instead of 25), that is why the dimension of weights vector and covariance matrix do not match.
Set noa this way:

```
noa = len(returns_daily.columns)
```

and you'll get the result

Comment: After moving noa under returns_daily, when I run the code, it nows gives this on the final piece of code `TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable`

Comment: This is because of a typo in your last line - write cov instead of cov()